# Is a covering map on compact metric space, $k$ - to- $1$ at all points?

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X$,$Y$ be topological space, surjective map
$\varphi:X\rightarrow Y$ is called a covering map if there is an
open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ of $Y$  such that for every $\alpha$,
$\varphi^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ is a disjoint union of open sets in $X$,
each of which is mapped by $\varphi$ homeomorphically onto
$U_{\alpha}$.

Question. Let $X, Y$ be compact metric spaces,

Is there is $k$ such that $\varphi$ is $k$- to- $1$ at all points?

Comment: Well, it is definitely false if you don't assume some connectedness.

Comment: If you assume that X is pathconnected, then it is true. The compactness gives you the finiteness of the fibre.

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal Given that they're metric spaces, just connectedness is enough.

Comment: I think in any case, as far as this result is concerned, connectedness alone is enough?

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal If you mean connected+compact, as opposed to path-connected+compact, then yes. If you mean connected _without_ compactness then it seems to me yes, if you allow $k$ to be an infinite cardinal: It's still true that for every $k$ the set of $x$ with a fiber of cardinality $k$ is open, and since this holds for every $k$ it's also closed.

Comment: Is the metric space assumption necessary? We can cover $Y$ by $U_i$ 's such that $\varphi ^{-1} (U_i)$  is a disjoint union and then cover $X$ by $\varphi ^{-1} (U_i)$. Since $X$ is compact, this has to have a finite subcover. But that gives finiteness of the fibres.

Comment: I meant to say that cover $X$ by the various disjoint sets appearing in $\varphi ^{-1}( U_i)$ for all $i$.

Comment: I am asking this because you wrote "*Given that they're metric spaces*, just connectedness is enough"

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal (power failure) Seems right - I said "metric" just because I hadn't thought about the general case, didn't want to tell any lies. (Speaking of which I just noticed I've had $X$ and $Y$ switched throughout all this, in case that makes anything I said make more sense...)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not if $Y$ is not connected; you could have a covering of this part of $Y$ that simply has nothing to do with a covering of that part of $Y$.

Yes, if $Y$ is connected. First you have to show that the inverse image of each point is finite (hint: If $x_j\ne x_k$ for $j\ne k$, $\phi(x_j)=y$ for all $j$ and $x_j\to x$ then $\phi$ cannot be a covering map).

Now for every $k$ the set of points of $Y$ that have exactly $k$ inverse images is open. Since this set is open for *every* $k$ it follows that it is closed...

Answer (score 0):

This is not true if $X$ is not connected. But is true if $X$ is connected since the function $g$ defined on $X$ such that $g(x)$ is the cardinal of the fiber of $x$ is continuous.

Comment: Well, I think you should mention that the "cardinal" is finite because of compactness.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume everything is connected and compact then the fiber over any point $y\in Y$ is given as the orbit of the deck-group transformation which is discrete and hence finite.